# Flow make a custom promise type

Tags: javascript, promise, flowtype

Well in my application I'm trying to add flow typing to sail's waterline orm.

To do so I tried adding a new class "_DeferredPromise", which is a `thenable` (or `promise`, as it's working with promise.all and await), however it adds a few extra functions to allow for chaining database queries. A typically signature for a table on the ORM would be:

```
type DatabaseORMTy<T> = {
  find: (number | {+[string]: mixed}) => _DeferredPromiseTy<$Array<T>>,
  //...
}
```

And deferredPromise:

```
type _DeferredPromiseTy<T> = {
  ...Promise<T>,
  fetch: () => _DeferredPromiseTy<T>,
  limit: (string|number) => _DeferredPromiseTy<T>,
  select: (?$ReadOnlyArray<string>) => _DeferredPromiseTy<T>,
  skip: (number) => _DeferredPromiseTy<T>,
  sort: (string) => _DeferredPromiseTy<T>,
  //and more
}
```

The problem is: I can't seem to let flow act as if those deferred promises *are* promises, just with a few more additional functions. I tried adding promise signature with `$Exact<Promise>` - which makes flow complain that you cannot make an exact promise. I tried adding them using `= Promise & {...}` and I tried above.

But those all show an error in use:

```
const data:T = await myTable.find(1).limit(1); //would find the entry with id=1, and at most 1 entry.
```

The following error shows up:

```
Error: Cannot call await with `find(...)` bound to `p` because  `_DeferredPromiseTy` [1] is incompatible with  `Promise` [2].
```

How do I make the custom type compatible with `Promise`?

An example, in try Flow (I notice that the error message is different there):
[fiddle](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAjOBnCB5ASgWQCogA8eAfFALxQDeAUFFAGYCWAdgCYBcUAFCwK4BbJBABOUAD7UA1AG1UwEawDmAXS4CmADwhsAvgEoKZAPowIDUSJ0AFEQHsN6AoQCCIkXCKkSAGjpQAegCAOlCaXQBuGmjQSChTc0sbe0cIZ1IKan9Q4NsHJnRiX38LYABjAAsubkNyEzMLd2T8py9i+gAbJg1gavlFFiVxfiFRWvrEprY81PT2qHQOiDLengB+ABIsCDg2DBYOkDcPIn7lEnH4hqTplIK0tr96VABrJjBqkeERS4TGq1uLQeRSeCzsIlW3DOg1+1ymM3uc1BQTg7CgAnBEHCURoADc4GIBCA8Mgllx4IgUOhsPhTgpzji0CAWGVGHwWcAmHYWIwWDUsvQytz5OiQNClKgOMdPIRxWRKHAAO5wJjAHhEklIJbBZjsbgARn0wS6PQN+n0UV0QA)

Comment: Would you be able to make a reproducible version? https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAjOBnCB5ASgWQCogA8eAfFALxQDeAUFFAGYCWAdgCYBcUAFCwK4BbJBABOUAD7UA1AG1UwEawDmAXS4CmADwhsAvgEoKZAPowIDUSJ0AFEQHsN6AoQCCIkXCKkSAGjpQAegCAOlCaXQBuGmjQSChTc0sbe0cIZ1IKan9Q4NsHJnRiX38LYABjAAsubkNyEzMLd2T8py9i+gAbJg1gavlFFiVxfiFRWvrEprY81PT2qHQOiDLengB+ABIsCDg2DBYOkDcPIn7lEnH4hqTplIK0tr96VABrJjBqkeERS4TGq1uLQeRSeCzsIlW3DOg1+1ymM3uc1BQTg7CgAnBEHCURoADc4GIBCA8Mgllx4IgUOhsPhTgpzji0CAWGVGHwWcAmHYWIwWDUsvQ4AB3OBMYDo4mkiDBZjsbgARn0wS6PQV+iiuiAA seems to work.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I've updated the example, the problem happens only on assigning the returned type, it never "collapses" the await.

Answer (score 1):

Flow gives `Promise` special treatment, and doesn't currently allow you to use `await` with custom Thenables. However, you can extend `Promise`, and Flow allows you to use instances of the subclass as `Promise`s.

You have a couple options:

You could use `declare class`, which makes Flow think there is a class of that type available. The downside here is that Flow will allow you to do things like `x instanceof _DeferredPromiseTy`, or attempt to construct it, even if there isn't actually any such class in reality.

```
declare class _DeferredPromiseTy<T> extends Promise<T> {
  fetch: () => _DeferredPromiseTy<T>,
  limit: (string|number) => _DeferredPromiseTy<T>,
  select: (?$ReadOnlyArray<string>) => _DeferredPromiseTy<T>,
  skip: (number) => _DeferredPromiseTy<T>,
  sort: (string) => _DeferredPromiseTy<T>,
  //and more
};
```

([playground](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAjOBnCB5ASgWQCogA8eAfFALxQDeAUFFAGYCWAdgCYBcUAFCwK4BbJBABOUAD7UA1AG1UwEawDmAXS4CmADwhsAvgEoKZAPowIDUSJ0AFEQHsN6AoQCCIkXCKkSAGjpQAegCAOlCaXQBuGmi2CABjABs4KyhEtFQoU3NLG3tHCGdSKAhNYAh2DNsHJnRiMlp6C2A4gAsubkNyEzMLd1zqpy9ffwSmDWB2+UUWJXF+IVFO7uy+tir8wuH6dAT4iZ4AfgASLAg4NgwWBJA3DyIp5RIlzJ6ctbyagqG-bYBrJjA7XmwhEzyyvSs7wGXzqPygqDsIn23AeMzBr1W60+mzhQTg7CgAkREHCURoADdkoSQHhkLsuPBECh0Nh8PcFI8yWgQCw4ow+LzgEw7CxGCwOtR-HERfJqailKgOLdPIR5WRKHAAO5wJjAHgCGl0iDBZjsbgARn0wVG4wt+n0UV0QA))

To solve that issue, you could actually define such a class. The downside here is that if you are just trying to add types to an existing codebase, it might not be structured in a way such that this is practical:

```
class _DeferredPromiseTy<T> extends Promise<T> {
  fetch(): _DeferredPromiseTy<T> { return this; }
  limit(x: string|number): _DeferredPromiseTy<T> { return this; }
  //and more
};
```

([playground](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAjOBnCB5ASgWQCogA8eAfFALxQDeAUFFAGYCWAdgCYBcUAFCwK4BbJBABOUAD7UA1AG1UwEawDmAXS4CmADwhsAvgEoKZAPowIDUSJ0AFEQHsN6AoQCCIkXCKkSAGjpQAegCAOlCaXQBuGmiAYwAbNFQoU3NLG3tHCGdSKAhNYAh2JNsHJnRiMlp6C2AYgAtufS4Ui3d00qcvSqgrYD4RFihgOrKIqF1-OKYNYG5NLnlFFiVxfiFRJuSzVqs2Eszs7t7+weHR8f8guHYoATsrcKiaADc4MQEQPGQ4iC54RBQ6Gw+CIi2UJCeaBALBijD4MOATDsgwYLEa1H8MWR8luIDBy1QHDcHlBCnBFCgcAA7nAmMAeB8vkgfsFmOxuABGfTBKYzTn6fRRXRAA))

Comment: I have difficulty accepting this answer, since the type of a third party library, so the "downside of adding a class" is quite real and impossible. So far it seems the only option though.